# OAuth 2.0 with complex or fine-grained scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

I am currently working on an OAuth2 implementation for all the clients (web and mobile). So far nothing fancy about it, but we want to have more complexity in the scope, so that we can grant partial access to certain objects down to the granularity of a single property.

**Example**: *Client gets access for a resource, let's say a user object with all its common properties. The client has full read access, but is only allowed to edit certain properties, e.g. password and username, but not location and/or birthday.*

So far my thoughts are, that this granularity is defined at the Authorization Server and just interpreted by the Resource Server.

Based on the RFC the scope is a string based comma separated value, so a plain list (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-23)

> The value of the scope parameter is expressed as a list of space-
> delimited, case-sensitive strings.  The strings are defined by the
> authorization server.  If the value contains multiple space-delimited
> strings, their order does not matter, and each string adds an
> additional access range to the requested scope.
>
> ```
>  scope       = scope-token *( SP scope-token )
>  scope-token = 1*( %x21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-7E )
> ```

So my first assumption providing json as the scope may not work, so I thought about introducing namespaces which might get to complex, e.g. (scope: user-write-full-read-*list of properties* or something similar).

Is there any best practice, am I missing something in the RFC or am I abusing OAuth completely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to consider the UMA protocol. The UMA RPT token is presented by the client to the Resource Server. The RPT token is issued by the Authorization Server (AS) with certain scopes. On the AS, scopes map to policies, such as who can get to what API's using which clients, network, required crypto, time of day, etc. These policies may be expressed in code or a more structured policy syntax like XACML, such as David suggested above.

If you want to learn more about UMA, I would start with this diagram:
  [image: UMA Overview]

In this case, there are two OAuth2 clients: the Resource Server (the thing with the APIs) and the Requesting Party (either a mobile application or web site).
The PAT and the AAT are normally OpenID Connect client tokens. The UMA Core spec says "OAuth2", but the only profile of OAuth2 for crypto client registration is OpenID Connect, so its implicit.

The Resource Owner is the one who makes the policies. These policies can be algorithmic or may require action by the Resource Owner. For more information about OpenID Connect, see

[OpenID Connect Website](http://openid.net/connect)

For more information about UMA see:

[UMA Website](https://kantarainitiative.org/confluence/display/uma/Home)

If you are looking for a free open source OAuth2 authorization server, you should take a look at the Gluu Server, which is an OpenID Connect Provider and an UMA Authorization Server for [FOSS Access Management](http://www.gluu.co/install-ce)

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about it. I think UMA was not designed to achieve fine-grained authorization, conversely, there are XACML which is specially designed to do that.

Even Gluu Server's main programmer (Michael Schwartz) says it in his book "Securing the perimeter"

`UMA does not enable fine-grained access control. This does not mean that policy centralization is not useful.`

Comment: Note, when I say "fine grained" I mean what the user can see in a page. For example, a page may display different content based on the role of the user. Think about an auction site, if you are the seller, you may see certain information. But if you are the buyer, you may see a different view. This is what I mean by fine grained access. It's efficient for the application to control the view.

Answer (score 8):

You're abusing OAuth here. Scopes are meant to define basic permissions but not fine grained access rights let alone authorization policies.

You should use XACML for that. In XACML, you also have the notion of an authorization server (the policy decision point or pdp). It's configured using policies. It sits in the infrastructure. It is queried at runtime by the policy enforcement point which protects your api/app.

Check out [developers.axiomatics.com](http://developers.axiomatics.com) for details (disclaimer: I work for Axiomatics)

Comment: True and I am also a lead contributor the XACML standard which is more relevant here

Comment: Remember, OAuth is a framework. It defines a common vocabulary--including the concept of scopes. At a high level, scopes define a client's extent of access. How an OAuth Authorization Server determines whether to grant a client a specific scope depends on the OAuth profile in use. I disagree with David here... you should not necessarily use XACML. It is one option of many, and is great for certain use cases--especially when you need a standard structured policy syntax.